# How to have a second desktop (using switcher) be empty (no folders of other icons)

Tags: cairo-dock, multiple-desktops

I am using switcher under cairo-dock.  I can switch to a second desktop but the clutter on my first desktop gets mirrored there (not the open windows, just the icons for folders and documents).  I'd like the second desktop to be clean (save for the dock, of course).  Any way to do that?  Thanks!!!